# How can I get keys of a name attribute

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this `name="opt['.$id.']" value="'.$points.'"` inside a checkbox input.Does anybody knows how I can get the `$id`?

UPDATED:

```
foreach($_POST['opt'] as $id => $value) { 

                $gift_ids = $value;
                $gift_ids2 = implode(", ", $gift_ids);
                               }
                    echo $gift_ids2;

    }
```

But I don't get any value on echo..

Comment: How I can get the `$id`? what do you mean by this? Please provide complete details while writing any question.

Comment: did you try a `print_r($_POST);` when the form is submitted to see what you recived in your post? (If the form is send via post.)

Comment: I get this `Array ( [opt] => Array ( [1] => 100 ) [eksasrgirwsh] => ) ` using `print_r`.But I really don't know how can I echo `$id` or store it in a database table..Any ideas?

Comment: @platanas20 Post questions about answers on the answer, don't update your question with provided answer and change the question. You have a trailing `}` and the `$gift_ids` is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the HTML array. Something like this should do it for you:

```
foreach($_POST['opt'] as $id => $value) {
```

Demo: https://eval.in/585379

Answer (score 1):

your used array so you need to Iterate the `$_POST['opt']` value

```
$_POST = array('opt' => array('1'=>100 ), 'eksasrgirwsh' => 'other');

foreach($_POST['opt'] as $id => $value) 
{

  echo   $id //key example 1

  echo  $value //value  example 100


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `$_POST` is like this

```
$_POST = array('opt' => array('1'=>100 ), 'eksasrgirwsh' => 'other');
```

and you are giving `$_POST['opt']` to foreach then your array for foreach is

```
$_POST['opt'] = array('1'=>100);
```

then you can't use `implode` in `foreach` because it give you an error. Do it without `implode`.

```
foreach($_POST['opt'] as $id => $value) { 

                $gift_ids = $value;

                echo $gift_ids;
                               }
```

Comment: You are right!But in this case `Array ( [1] => 100 [2] => 200 )` I want to store both ids in the database.Instead of this I store only the second id (2)..

Comment: Maybe you are right but I cannot find what goes wrong

Comment: @platanas20 Well we're not magicians so your going to have to provide a detailed description and code for **exactly** what you actually are trying to do.